# Understanding etoolbox macro \deflength

Tags: macros, calculations, etoolbox

The `etoolbox` package documentation says about `\deflength`:

> This command may be used as a drop-in replacement for `\setlength`.

I am having trouble getting it to work with the `\minof` macro from the `calc` package. The following MWE gives me a

```
"missing number, treated as zero"
```

error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength{\foo}
\begin{document}
\deflength{\foo}{\minof{1in}{2in}}
\setlength{\foo}{\minof{1in}{2in}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks like it is a drop in replacement for the standard `\setlength` not the version from the `calc` package (which is quite different)

Comment: `calc` documentation: If `\minof` and `\maxof` are used with dimensions or glue  `these macros are allowed only as part of addition and subtraction

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the example from the calc documentation does not work with `\deflength`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't realize (but probably should have) that calc redefined `\setlength`.

Comment: @StrongBad: Yes, `calc` does a lot of redefinitions of `\setlength` as well as `\stepcounter` etc. And I know, it won't work with `addition` etc. here with `\deflength`, but your example as `multiplications` as well

Comment: @StrongBad that's just about _all_ it does:-)

Comment: I was going to show how to do the calculation without either package but your example is the product of two lengths????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not need the rest of calc, I just need `\minof`. I will edit the MWE (again).

Comment: minof is (or could be)  just `\def\minof#1#2{\ifdim#1<#2#1\else#2\fi}` you don't need 300 lines of scary calc macro definitions for that:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `calc` package does a lot of redefinitions of `\setlength` as well as `\stepcounter` etc. It won't work with addition etc. or with `\deflength`. Here's a `\minof` wrapper that works with `\deflength` since it uses the `etoolbox` macro `\ifdimgreater`.

`\ifdimgreater` and `\ifdimless` are wrappers fro `\ifdimcomp`.

Both macros work this way `\ifdim...{first dim}{second dim}{true code}{false code}`

Please note that `\deflength{}` can work with additions and subtractions of lengths in its argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\etminof}[2]{%
  \ifdimgreater{#1}{#2}{%
    #2%
  }{%
    #1% Is smaller or equal
  }%
}


\newcommand{\etmaxof}[2]{%
  \ifdimgreater{#1}{#2}{%
    #1%
  }{%
    #2% Is greater or equal
  }%
}


\newlength{\foo}

\newlength{\foobar}

\begin{document}


\deflength{\foo}{\etminof{1in}{2in}}

\deflength{\foobar}{\etmaxof{5in}{10in}}

% Outputting the whole stuff
\the\foo

\the\foobar

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Here's some edition with `\ifdim` and `expl3` version as well**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand{\etminof}[2]{%
  \ifdimgreater{#1}{#2}{%
    #2%
  }{%
    #1% Is smaller or equal
  }%
}


\newcommand{\etmaxof}[2]{%
  \ifdimgreater{#1}{#2}{%
    #1%
  }{%
    #2% Is greater or equal
  }%
}

\newcommand{\texminof}[2]{%
  \ifdim#1<#2
  #1%
  \else
  #2%
  \fi
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\explminof}[2]{%
  \dim_min:nn {#1} {#2}
% or
%  \dim_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {#2}
%  {#1} % True 
%  {#2} % False
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newlength{\foo}

\begin{document}

\texttt{etoolbox}
\deflength{\foo}{\etminof{5in}{10in}}

\the\foo

Now \LaTeXe

\deflength{\foo}{\texminof{5in}{10in}}

\the\foo



Now \texttt{expl3}

\deflength{\foo}{\explminof{5in}{10in}}


\the\foo



\end{document}
```

Comment: There is `\dim_min:nn`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I overlooked that in the manual